# How to K.clear_session() within GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, grid-search

I am using GridSearchCV from sklearn and get the error message:

> Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor
>   Tensor("masking_1_input:0", shape=(?, 300, 31), dtype=float32) is not
>   an element of this graph.

which can be prevented through using K.clear_session() after each run. So far, I have not found any possibilities to include this function in GridSearchCV. Do you know how it could work?

I have tried to implement it as a callback with on_train_end(), but that would clear the session too early and produces another error message:

**Update**

I have found out that the error is connected to the callbacks TensorBoard and ModelCheckpoint. When i remove them the GridSearch works. With the other two callbacks Histories, ReduceLROnPlateau and EarlyStopping the GridSearch works without any problems. 
The similarity between those two callbacks is that both save a file on the computer. the code for the two callbacks is:

```
callback_tb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="D:/logs/"name + '_' + str(count) + 'days', write_graph = True, write_grads = True, histogram_freq=5, write_images = True )
checkpointer = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath='D:/tmp/'name+ '_' + str(count)+'.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
```

Comment: What is this error message when you use `callback`?